# JQuery dataTable does not work with haml - Ruby - (sinatra)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable, haml

I'm trying to use a dataTable in my ruby project with Sinatra.

Instead of HTML pages w're using HAML-files.

My first idea was to make a normal table we could create if we looped trough our array, that worked out verry well. But since we wanted to use this table as a dataTable with JQuery & javascript, We are having some issues.

So to figer out what the problem was, I created a simple haml table with data in each TableRow.

```
%table{:id => "test"}
  %thead
    %tr
      %th data1
      %th data2
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td data3
      %td data14
    %tr
      %td data15
      %td data16
    %tr
      %td data17
      %td data18
```

So when I saw the installation manual on DataTables.net it said we had to import the CSS-Styling and the 2 jquery files.

So said so done in my laout.haml file:

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %meta{:charset => 'utf-8'}
    %title tooltitle 
    %link{:href => "./css/jquery-ui-1.10.4.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}/
    %link{:charset => "utf-8", :href => "./css/2close.css", :media => "screen", :rel =>     "stylesheet", :type => "text/css"}/
    %link{:href => "./css/multi-select.css", :media => "screen", :rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css"}/
    %link{:href => "./css/login.css", :media => "screen", :rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css"}/
    %link{:href => "./DataTables-1.10.3/media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css", :media => "screen", :rel => "stylesheet", :type => "text/css"}/
    %script{:src => "./scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js",:type => "text/javascript"}
    %script{:src => "./scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
    %script{:src => "./scripts/jquery.multi-select.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
    %script{:src => "./DataTables-1.10.3/media/js/jquery.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
    %script{:src => "./DataTables-1.10.3/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js", :type => "text/javascript"}**  
    %script{:src => "./scripts/scripts.js", :type => "text/javascript"}
    %script{:src => "./scripts/test.js"}
```

so as you can see, we are using multiple jquery files and multiple css files ! 
As you might think the link is not correct ==> we've checked it before. 
We have our public directory, with the DataTables folder inside of it. 
Other Javascript files and css-files do work with our site.

Last but not least, we had to initiate our DataTable:

```
:javascript
  $(document).ready( function() 
  {
  $('#test').DataTable();

  }
```

This is a screenshot of the table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK fixed my own problem! 
I had to use the datatable iniatie for this table-id,

witouht using the  $(document).ready( function()

```
 $('#test').DataTable();
```

I'm just wondering why this actually works if i don't use the load statement. 
In the Datatables.net - website, this is the only initiate you have to do!

Comment: If you use Turbolinks in your Rails app, such a gem pretty much defuncts `$(document).ready()`. Instead, you have to use `$(document).on('page:change', function () {...})`. That was my experience when `$(document).ready()` did not work.